# A Job Already Exists. How can I delete a job?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a multiple jobs was finished on Iot Hub. How can I delete a job using SDK? I know the JobID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [CancelJobAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.registrymanager.canceljobasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_RegistryManager_CancelJobAsync_System_String_) method which is in RegistryManager class to cancel or delete the job with the specified ID. You can find the RegistryManager class in [Microsoft.Azure.Devices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Devices/) sdk. This sdk is service SDK for Azure IoT Hub.

And more, you can also use [CancelJobAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.jobclient.canceljobasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Devices_JobClient_CancelJobAsync_System_String_) method in [JobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.jobclient?view=azure-dotnet) to implement ,it is included in Microsoft.Azure.Devices SDK too.